# Changing navbar border-bottom on scroll using Javascript

Tags: javascript, scroll

I'm trying to make the border-bottom of my navbar appear only after I scroll down but couldn't make it work so far.

This is the JS I'm using:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$(window).on("scroll",function(){
var wn = $(window).scrollTop();
if(wn > 100){
  $(".semplice-navbar").css("border-bottom-color:","rgba(0,0,0,1)");
}
else{
  $(".semplice-navbar").css("border-bottom-color:","rgba(0,0,0,0)");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing ":" when you call your element in css method like in the code below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).on("scroll",function(){
    var wn = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(wn > 100){
        $(".semplice-navbar").css("border-bottom-color","rgba(0,0,0,1)");
    }
    else{
        $(".semplice-navbar").css("border-bottom-color","rgba(0,0,0,0)");
    }
```

instead of

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).on("scroll",function(){
    var wn = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(wn > 100){
        $(".semplice-navbar").css("border-bottom-color:","rgba(0,0,0,1)");
    }
    else{
        $(".semplice-navbar").css("border-bottom-color:","rgba(0,0,0,0)");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work, could it be anything else?

Comment: Do you have any error in your browser Console ? It's working for me